# Joomla! - Unable to log in

Tags: authentication, joomla

I'm using Joomla 1.5.22.

I tried to manually insert a new user to the 'site_users' table in the database.
But when i tried to log in with the new user, the page just refresh but doesn't log in.

May i know why is that so?
Sorry as i'm a beginner in programming and Joomla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new user the best solution is to :

1. login to the administrator page : http://www.yourwebsiteurl/administrator
2. then go to user management and create a new user

Don't try to insert a new user with a MySQL request, use the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin is right.

If you want to add new user, then best way for you to add it from backend.

Actually, Joomla use do not depend only on one table #__user, with each entry of user, there access level are also maintained in some other tables. like core_acl_pro, acl_group etc

Password of user are md5 hashed of password and a random salt.

So its better to create user from backend.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Kevin

Password are hashed when stored in the database. So you cannot store this information without knowning what you do!